# Applying compose to fmap

Tags: haskell, types, composition

For weeks I've been trying to figure out how the Haskell compiler applies the (.) to fmap.

What I mean is.

```
:t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

:t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

:t (.) fmap
(.) fmap :: Functor f => (a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> f a1 -> f b
```

How did the compiler arrive at the type for (.) fmap?

I was actually going to ask this question here but while I was explaining what I've tried it all came together. So now I'm just going to post the answer too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get this I took fmap

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

if

```
:t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

then

(b -> c) of the start of the (.) function can be replaced with

```
((a -> b) -> (f a -> f b))
```

thus I have

```
((a1 -> b) -> (f a1 -> f b)) -> (a -> (a1 -> b)) -> a -> (f a1 -> f b)
```

Since (.) has been applied to fmap, we can eliminate ((a1 -> b) -> (f a1 -> f b)) and we are left with

```
(a -> (a1 -> b)) -> a -> (f a1 -> f b)
```

Then to be extra clean we can eliminate extra parentheses.

Glguy and Hamme from the IRC Beginner-haskell channel both reminded me (->) is right associative

e.g. (a -> b -> c -> d)  = (a -> (b -> (c -> d)))

so we eliminate the redundant parentheses.

```
(a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> f a1 -> f b

:t (.) fmap
(.) fmap :: Functor f => (a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> f a1 -> f b
```

Comment: I think you are missing an arrow there ((a1 -> b) -> (f a1 -> f b)) -> (a -> (a1 -> b)) -> a -> (f a1 -> f b)

Comment: I added the arrow. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The type signature can be understood intuitively if you rename `a` to `c`, rename `a1` to `a`, and add an extra pair of parentheses:

```
> :t (.) fmap
(.) fmap :: Functor f => (c -> (a -> b)) -> c -> f a -> f b
```

The first argument is a function that returns another function `(a -> b)` that gets fed into `fmap`. Applying the first argument produces the fully composed function waiting on that one argument `c`. Applying `c` produces `fmap (a -> b)` which is only waiting on the last argument `f a`.

```
   ((.) fmap)
   ((.) fmap (c -> (a -> b))     -- Apply the 1st argument
   ((.) fmap (c -> (a -> b)) c   -- Apply the 2nd argument
   fmap (a -> b)
   fmap (a -> b) f a             -- Apply the 3rd argument
   f b                           -- The result
```

An example:

```
> ((.) fmap) (\n -> (+n)) 42 [1..5]  -- Becomes: fmap (+42) [1..5]
[43,44,45,46,47]
> ((.) fmap) (\n -> (+n)) 13 [1..5]
[14,15,16,17,18]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to understand how the type is derived is to look at what `(fmap .)` means.

Consider `fmap . g`: what does this mean? Expanding the definition of `.`, we see that `fmap . g = \x -> fmap (g x)`. Since the first argument to `fmap` needs to be a function with type `a -> b`, `g` must be function with a type like `c -> a -> b`; it *computes* an appropriate function given an argument.

Now, whereas we can apply `fmap f` directly to a list (or other functor), we need to give `fmap . g` an argument first:

```
fmap f someFunctorialValue == someOtherFunctorialValue
((fmap . g) x) someFunctorialValue == someOtherFunctorialValue
```

Dropping some redundant parentheses, this becomes

```
(fmap .) g x someFunctorialValue == someOtherFunctorialValue
```

and now we can directly what the type of each expression should be:

```
-- someFunctorialValue :: Functor f => f a
-- someOtherFunctorialValue :: Functor f => f b
-- x :: c
-- g :: (c -> a -> b)
-- (fmap .) :: (c -> a -> b) -> c -> f a -> f b
-- fmap     :: (     a -> b)      -> f a -> f b
```

In other words: `fmap` takes a concrete function `a -> b`, while `(fmap .)` takes a "parameterized" function `g` and a "function selector" `x`.